# Git merged without me asking? Why?

Tags: git

I was working on master, finished up what I needed to do, then did

```
git commit -am "message".
```

I wanted to test out writing a new feature, so I did:

```
git branch NewFeature
```

followed by

```
git checkout NewFeature
```

I then made changes to version controlled files, came back to git and did

```
git checkout master
```

What I forgot to do was commit those changes to the NewFeature branch. My fault, yes, but looking around on SO it seems like that should have failed without the -f flag. Unfortunately, it just merged my changes with master. Naturally I freaked out and did

```
git reset --hard head
```

It seems like I lost all the work I had done on the NewFeature branch when I switched back as well! What did I do wrong?

Comment: Not answering your question, but two of your commands could be combined into `git checkout -b NewFeature`.  (And if it's not exactly equivalent, someone will point it out in a few minutes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is normal behavior.**

If you don't have conflicting changes between branches, git simply "moves" the changes over when you checkout. Git should show you a summary of the moved files after the checkout.

Doing `git reset --hard HEAD` will have reverted your changes.

### More info

If you have uncommitted changes but you want to work on other things in a different branch, you can stash your changes for later. [See **stash** docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

- `git stash`
- `git checkout <branch>`
- *Make your changes and commit*
- `git checkout <oldBranch>`
- `git stash pop` *to un-stash*

Comment: Hmm, so the only proper way to do this would be to have committed before trying to switch? Thanks

Comment: Just added info on other ways to do work on multiple branches

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider looking at 'git reflog' to find out the state of the branches in order to restore you changes.

But as you noted, `git reset --hard` is an operation which changes the working tree, as noted in the man page:

```
       --hard
           Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files
           in the working tree since <commit> are discarded.
```

I wrote more about the reflog in my weekly Git Tip of the Week series here:

http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/05/git-tip-of-week-reflogs.html

Comment: Thanks for the edits, guys. I blame Lion for automatically changing the spelling when I wasn't looking ...